# Google's Python Course: iterating through list of regular expressions and printing each output on a new line

Tags: python, regex, tuples

I am trying to pass some regular expressions examples that are provided by Google's Python Course to a list and print each output on a new line.

```
import re
str='an example word:cat!!'
match=re.search(r'word:\w\w\w',str)
if match:
  print('I found a cat :)',match.group()) ## 'found word:cat'
else:
  print('did not find')


matches=[re.search(r'pi+', 'piiig'),re.search(r'i+', 'piigiiii'),re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d', 'xx1 2   3xx'),re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d', 'xx12  3xx'),re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d', 'xx123xx'),re.search(r'^b\w+', 'foobar'),re.search(r'b\w+', 'foobar')]
for the_match in matches:
  matches.append(the_match)
print("\n".join(matches))
#del matches
```

When I run `python regex.py`, I get the following:

```
python regex.py
I found a cat :) word:cat
```

It just stalls and produces no further output. I will have to press `ctrl+c` 2 times to exit.

Please let me how to get an output such as:

```
re.search(r'pi+', 'piiig') returned (<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='piii'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3), match='ii'>)
re.search(r'i+', 'piigiiii') returned <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3), match='ii'>
etc...
```

I am running Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10 version 10.0.10586 64 bit.

Thank you!

After your answers (@Buzz), my script is as follows:

```
import re
str='an example word:cat!!'
match=re.search(r'word:\w\w\w',str)
matches=[re.search(r'pi+', 'piiig'),re.search(r'i+', 'piigiiii'),re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d', 'xx1 2   3xx'),re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d', 'xx12  3xx'),re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d', 'xx123xx'),re.search(r'^b\w+', 'foobar'),re.search(r'b\w+', 'foobar')]

if match:
  print('I found a cat :)',match.group()) ## 'found word:cat'
else:
  print('No match found.')

for the_match in matches:
  print(the_match)
```

The output is as follows:

```
I found a cat :) word:cat
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='piii'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3), match='ii'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 9), match='1 2   3'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 7), match='12  3'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 5), match='123'>
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 6), match='bar'>
```

This works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it keeps running forever is becasue you are appending to `matches` inside the for loop. You are always adding to it making the list longer which in turn makes the for loop run until it can reach the end, but it will never reach it.

```
for the_match in matches:
    print (the_match)
```

Comment: I removed ` matches.append(the_match` and changed the `print` line to `print(the_match)` and it worked. I will update my question with the new script Thank you @Buzz

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop:

```
for the_match in matches:
  matches.append(the_match)
```

This will append new items to the list forever. I don't know what you were trying to achieve with this, but it looks like you can simply remove these two lines.

Comment: Thank you. I removed those 2 lines and got `I found a cat :) word:cat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regex.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("\n".join(matches))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, _sre.SRE_Match found` Then, I changed the `print` line to `print("\n".join(str(matches))` and got `I found a cat :) word:cat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regex.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("\n".join(str(matches)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.